# Problem when I log into Facebook in Tkinter and Selenium, using the textboxes for user and password

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I would like to log into Facebook after entering username and password in a tkinter window. The problem is that, after entering the username and password, when I click on the Login button, the facebook page opens but without logging in. Maybe it's some problem with driver.find_element. How to solve?
NOTE: Please don't change the way I connect with Firefox.

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry('630x500')

topbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3c5999', height=42)
topbar.pack(fill='x')


#TEXTBOX
label_email = Label(root, text="email", bg='#3c5999', foreground="white")
label_email.place(x=2, y = 10)
email = tk.Entry(root)
email.place(x=50, y = 9)

label_password = Label(root, text="password", bg='#3c5999', foreground="white")
label_password.place(x=260, y = 10)
password = tk.Entry(root)
password.place(x=335, y = 9)


def login():
    #Access Facebook
    profile_path = '/usr/bin/firefox/firefox'
    #/usr/bin/firefox/firefox


    options=Options()
    options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 4)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)

    service = Service('/home/jass/bin/geckodriver')
    driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "accept_only_essential_button"))).click()   

    username_box = driver.find_element('email')
    username_box.send_keys(email)
      
    password_box = driver.find_element('pass')
    password_box.send_keys(password)
      
    login_box = driver.find_element('loginbutton')
    login_box.click()


button = Button(root, text="Login", bg='white', foreground='black', width=7, command=login)
button.place(x=530, y=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: did you run in console to see error messages? Maybe you hav emistake and it can't login.

Comment: you have to use `email.get()` and `password.get()` to get text from `Entry`

Comment: you use `find_element` in wrong way - it has to be `find_element(By.ID, 'email')` eventually older `find_element_by_id('email')`. But this you should see if you would run code in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would run code in console then you should see errors which should help you to see problem.

You have two mistakes.

- you use `find_element()` in wrong way - it has to be `find_element(By.ID, 'email')` eventually older `find_element_by_id('email')` (the same for `pass` and `button`
- you have to use `.get()` to get text from `Entry` - so you need `email.get()` and `password.get()`

```
    username_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
    username_box.send_keys(email.get())
      
    password_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
    password_box.send_keys(password.get())
      
    login_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginbutton')
    login_box.click()
```

---

There is also other problem (at least on my computer) - at start it shows message about cookies and I have to close it because it hides `loginbutton` and Selenium can't click it.

---

**EDIT:**

To close cookie message you have to use correct css selector

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-cookiebanner="accept_only_essential_button"]')
```

and you have to wait longer than 1 second.

---

Full working code:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk     # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions after imports

def login():
    profile_path = '/usr/bin/firefox/firefox'

    options = Options()
    options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 4)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)

    service = Service('/home/jass/bin/geckodriver')
    driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")       # https instead of http

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-cookiebanner="accept_only_essential_button"]'))).click()   

    username_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
    username_box.send_keys(email.get())
      
    password_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
    password_box.send_keys(password.get())
      
    login_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginbutton')
    login_box.click()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry('630x500')

topbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3c5999', height=42)
topbar.pack(fill='x')

label_email = tk.Label(topbar, text="email", bg='#3c5999', foreground="white")
label_email.place(x=2, y=10)

email = tk.Entry(topbar)
email.place(x=50, y=9)

label_password = tk.Label(topbar, text="password", bg='#3c5999', foreground="white")
label_password.place(x=260, y=10)

password = tk.Entry(topbar)
password.place(x=335, y=9)

button = tk.Button(topbar, text="Login", bg='white', foreground='black', width=7, command=login)
button.place(x=530, y=5)

root.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Yes true. I forgot to write the code to click on cookies. I use this WebDriverWait (driver, 1) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "accept_only_essential_button"))). Click (), but it doesn't work. Now I've added it to my code in the question. Do you know how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: you may have to wait longer - you wait only 1second.

Comment: if you use `css selector then you have to use correct value - using `accept_only_essential_button` it tries to find tag `<accept_only_essential_button>` but `accept_only_essential_button` is value in `data-cookiebanner` so you may need something like `button[data-cookiebanner="accept_only_essential_button"]`